# Getting button names from loop in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create restaurant management system that I designed the foods and other services to represent in buttons so one ever button to save the button's name and the number of clicks in the textbox(receipt). It would look like this:
[image]

My problem is how to get the button text generated by a for loop and inset into textbox

This is part of my code:

```
def readbreakfast():  #this reads food names from database
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM breakfast")
    return cur.fetchall()

def showbreakfast(): #this reads names into buttons
    global name
    data1 = readbreakfast()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data1):
       name= ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda row=index+1:update_count(row))
       name.grid(row=index+1, column=0,padx=0, pady=0)
def update_count(value):   #this gets button name and number of clicks 
    global bttn,bttn_clicks,my_text
    my_text=StringVar()
    my_text = dat.cget('text')
    bttn_clicks += 1
    bttn = IntVar()
    global variable
    variable = value
    print(update_count)


def Receipt():   #text of the button that is clicked is to insert here
    txtReceipt.delete("1.0", END)
    x = random.randint(10908, 500876)
    randomRef = str(x)
    Receipt_Ref.set("BILL" + randomRef)

    txtReceipt.insert(END, 'Receipt Ref: \t\t\t'+Receipt_Ref.get()+"\t\t"+DateofOrder.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END, 'Items\t\t'+'Quantity\t\t\t'+"Price \n\n")

    if variable == 1:
        txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")
     if variable == 2:
        txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")

        I have found different code examples but nothing specific enough to implement into my program. Any advice is much appreciated!
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with names ? The text on the button?

Comment: Can you use `index` to get text from `dat` ?

Comment: thanks jakob I mean the text of the button yes

Comment: Zety yes I can use to get the text but I need this when inserting into the textbox

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. It's not at all obvious what belongs in `showqurec` and `update_count`.

Comment: Also, why are you defining `row` in your lambda and never using it? You're always passing the hard-coded value of `1` to `update_count`.

Comment: @Zety just noticing that the OP didn't ping you, so just in case see the above comments ( *Zety yes I can use to get the text but I need this when inserting into the textbox – `mohamed abdallah`* ).

Comment: Why you did get text label in for loop using `index` value ?

Comment: @BryanOakley  please can share with all the if you can help me please

Comment: @Zety please  I need   a help if can brother

Comment: sorry to be so late, button texts are they stored or you want to make transformation inside a for loop.

Comment: @zety they I want to make transformation inside the for loop  look back at my code I edited a little bit  or my I share with you all the code   and all thak to u <3

Comment: As I see in your code button text came from `SELECT name FROM breakfast` ? and please add a sample result of executing that request.